# JPG is uploaded in Jmeter but it is corrupt when downloaded

Tags: file-upload, jmeter

I am trying to upload the jpg file in jmeter and the file is uploaded (not with the right extension I suppose) and when tried to download it then file size is exactly same as the original jpg size but it is corrupt. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your `type="file"` Parameter Name:

[image]

so most probably the problem is somewhere around this setting.

However I might be wrong, the easiest way of creating the file upload request in JMeter is just recording it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

The only thing you need to do is to copy your `apple.jpg` file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter will be able to properly capture and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: I also feel that the issue is with passing parameter type="file". I have also put the jpg file inside bin folder but not sure why jmeter is not recording the upload file scenario. Any idea? I have used Recording template to record the script.